# One outlet in house is hot while turning all breakers off

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, safety, fire-hazard

One outlet does not appear to be attached to a breaker in the breaker panel.  Only in shutting the main breaker off does that outlet lose electricity.  Is this dangerous?  Is there a remedy?

Comment: Is your main breaker part of the electrical panel, or separate from it?

Comment: When you switched off the branch circuit breakers did you switch each one off and then, when that didn't cut the power to the receptacle, switch it back on before going to the next breaker? If so, the fault could be that two breakers are (improperly) feeding this receptacle. You have all the branch breakers off at the same time to be sure.

Comment: If you switch off all the branch breakers at the same time (but leave the main on) and the receptacle is unpowered , then let us know and we can tell you how to determine which breakers are powering it.

Comment: What kind of panel do you have: (1) one main breaker which controls all the other breakers (120 V single pole and 240 V double pole) so that one flip shuts off all power, or (2) a set of four to six 240 V breakers one of which is the "main" breaker for all the 120 V breakers but not for the 240 V breakers (so up to six flips required to shut off all power)?

Comment: How did you determine that the receptacle is still hot? If you plug a lamp into it, will it light?

Comment: Did you just check the single pole 15 and 20 amp breakers or did you check the 2-pole breakers to major appliances and equipment also?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely dangerous. The main breaker is for a very high amperage (like 100 amps). If there's no other breaker between the main breaker and the outlet, a high amperage would be needed to trip it.

I doubt the wires to the outlet could be sized appropriatedly. And I doubt it is allowed to have a regular outlet on a high amperage breaker.

Maybe a sub-panel or a breaker you missed ?